# Qualtrics: Pressing the space bar to move forward to the next question in the "Text/Graphic" type of question

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I know very little about Java Script, but I need to add a custom code to my Qualtrics survey that makes pressing the spacebar continues the survey in the "Text/Graphic" question type.

I've already found out the Java Script code for the multiple choice type of question on Qualtrics, but it doesn't work for the text/graphic questions.

I need your help, please! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This sounds like you want to set focus traversal. Read about focus traversal in Javascript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck